# Override default wordpress startup

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have installed wordpress at the root (httpdocs).
When I enter domain url wordpress theme loads.

All ok, except that for now I would like that my old static index.html page is loaded instead, and that I can access wordpress with direct URI ...like /index.php

I think I need to modify .htaccess somehow for this to work? somehow I am not successfull at this. Maybe something needs to be reconfigured in wordpress as well?

I would appreciate some experts help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]
```

before the Rules added by WordPress (before `# BEGIN WordPress`). This will match the request for / (and only that) and rewrite it to /index.html. The L flag indicates that no other rules shall be executed.

To give logged in WP users the WP site instead of your static page, use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !wordpress_logged_in
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]
```

But why don't you just convert your static home page into the front-page for WordPress? See [the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page) for more info and examples.

Comment: This always trows me to index.html which is ok. But how can I access wp theme now for testing and preparing content? I will check front page link in a mean time... this is my first work with wp.

Comment: You should probably put your development site on a sub domain, but I've edited my post to add the option to show the WP site for logged in users. Go to /wp-admin/, log in and then visit your homepage, you should now see the WP version.

Comment: Thanks jan. In a mean time I also managed to setup static front page. It is my first time working with wordpress (or any other system like it and I need to explore my way around it. Yes. I should put development under subdomain. I will also try this redirect with a cookie. Thanks!